# Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ of degree greater than $1$ defined by $g_i(x)$ .Find the average of the roots of $g_{89}(x)$.

Tags: polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ of degree greater than $1$.Degine
>   $g_i(x)$ by $g_1(x)=f(x)$,and $g_{k+1}(x)=f(g_{k}(x))$.Let $r_k$ be the
>   average of the roots of $g_k$.Determine $r_{89}$ if $r_{19}=89$.

**My effort**

Playing with the definitions I can see that 
\begin{array}
gg_1(x)&=f(x) \\
g_2(x) &=f(g_1(x))=f(f(x))=f^2(x) \\
g_3(x) &=f(g_2(x))=f(f^2(x))=f^3(x) \\
\end{array}

And so on... In general I have that $$g_{k+1}=f^{k+1}(x)$$.

If I let now $$p(x)=p_nx^n+p_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+p_1x+p_0$$ and 
$$q(x)=q_nx^n+q_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+q_1x+q_0$$

Then, $$p(q(x))=p_n(q_nx^n+q_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+q_1x+q_0)^n+p_{n-1}(q_nx^n+q_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+q_1x+q_0)^{n-1}+\cdots+p_1(q_nx^n+q_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+q_1x+q_0)+p_0 $$

Now the sum of the roots of $(p(q(x))$ is given by the coefficient of $x^{{n^2}-1}$ which is,if I didn't make any mistake, $\dbinom{n}{1}\cdot p_n \cdot q_{n}^{n-1}\cdot q_{n-1}$

So the average of the roots is given by $$\cfrac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}=-\cfrac{\dbinom{n}{1}\cdot p_n \cdot q_{n}^{n-1}\cdot q_{n-1}}{n}$$

Now I am quite stuck on how to best proceed from here ...

Comment: Is this again from the American Regions Mathematics League ? (Because I find this question interesting)

Comment: Nope.This is from Mathematical Mayhem :)

Comment: Just to be sure : does "greater than 1" mean $>1$ or $≥1$ ? (I don't know if this is essential…)

Comment: @Watson It's the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f=a\,x^n-b\,x^{n-1}+\dots$; then $r_1=b/(n\,a)$. According to you calculations (with $p=q=f$) we have
$$
f^2=a^{n+1}x^{n^2}-n\,a^n\,b\,x^{n^2-1}+\dots\implies r_2=\frac{n\,a^n\,b}{n^2\,a^{n+1}}=\frac{b}{n\,a}.
$$
Once you see this, you suspect that $r_k$ is constant, and it is not difficult to prove it by an induction argument.

Another way of reasoning is the following. Let $x_i$, $1\le i\le n$, be the roots of $f$. Then $r_1=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. The set of roots of $f^2$ is the union of the solutions of the equations $f=x_i$, $1\le i\le n$. The polynomial $f-x_i$ has teh same coefficients as $f$, except for the independent term. It follows that the average of the roots of $f-x_i$ is the same as the average of the roots of $f$, and that the average of the roots of $f^2$ is the same as the average of the roots of $f$.

Comment: I am having some difficulty understanding where the extra factor of $n$  in the denominator of $r_2$ comes from ...Can you help ?

Comment: Is the degree of $f^2$ (equal to the number of roots). If $f$ is of degree $n$, then $f^2$ is of degree $n^2$.

Comment: Right,thanks again.