# Roots of iterations of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, fractals, complex-dynamics

Let $f \in \Bbb Q[X]$ a polynomial, and let denote by $f^n$ the composition $\underbrace{f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{n \text{ times }}$.

Let $R(f^n) \subset \Bbb C$ the roots of $f^n$. I'm interested in knowing how $R(f^n)$ behaves as $n \to \infty$.

Here is an example :

- $g(x) = 0.5 x^5-0.5x-1$, with $n=1,2,3$
  [image: -1-0.5 x+0.5 x^5]

Here are some questions :

1. Is it true that $R(g^n)$ is "uniformly bounded", i.e. there is a ball of radius $r>0$ that contains all the $R(g^n)$ ? This is clearly false for the polynomials $X-a, (a≠0)$. But it seems that this could be true for the $g(x) = 0.5 x^5-0.5x-1$ (and also for many other examples I've tried).

   I think that the average of the roots of $f^n$ is [constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1641629) if $\deg(f) ≥ 2$, but I don't know if this helps.
2. [soft question] Looking at the "fractal" pattern for $g^3$ (see above ; again this happens for other polynomials), I have somehow the intuition that $R(g^n)$ "converges" to some set $R \subset \Bbb C$.

   How could I formalize this idea, and then possibly prove that my intuition can be turned into a "theorem" ?

   In order to formalize this idea, my attempt was to consider a collection $(x_{m,k})_{k≥1}$ of Cauchy sequences such that $\bigcup_{n≥1} R(g^n) = \bigcup_{m≥1} \{x_{m,k} \mid k ≥ 1\}$ and $x_{m,k} \in R(g^k)$. There should be better (and more correct) ways to formalize my intuition…

Thank you for your comments !

---

I did the pictures with Mathematica. I tried to see what happens for $g^4$, but it was completely wrong (because $g^4$ has degree $625$, which is pretty large, I presume). I hope that there is no error with the fact that $g^3$ has degree $125$.

Comment: If $\deg f > 1$, then there is an $R$ with $\lvert z\rvert > R \implies \lvert f(z)\rvert > \lvert z\rvert$, so for all polynomials $f$ of degree at least $2$, $R(f^n)$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer : thank you! I didn't thought to this because I was probably too "intrigued" by the apparently "fractal" behaviour of $R(g^3)$…

Comment: Instead of solving equations of very high degree, solve equations of fixed degree by finding the inverse images of zeros, the inverse images of inverse images of zeros, etc.

Comment: Some interesting things to look at that might be related: Late work of Thurston (e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.2008v1.pdf) and this discussion of roots of polynomials by Baez (http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/).

Comment: The picture that you are showing looks like Mandelbrot's fractal.

Comment: It's worthy of note that the notion of a sequence of (compact) sets converging is well defined - for instance, in a metric space $(M,d)$ define $d(A,x)$ for a compact set $A$ and point $x$ to be $\inf_{a\in A}d(a,x)$. Then, define the function $d'(A,B)$ for two compact sets $A$ and $B$ as $\sup_{b\in B}d(A,b)$. Then, $d(A,B)=max(d'(A,B),d'(B,A))$ is a metric. I seem to recall some result about it being complete too (but it's been too long since I saw that result). In any case, asking about convergence in this metric is reasonable. The set would be fixed under the preimage of $g$.

Comment: @Milo Brandt. If $(M,d)$ i a compact metric space the metric $d'$ on the set of non-empty closed subsets is complete.

Comment: @lhf Good point! I used that to help me improve my answer a bit.

Comment: Using SAGE commands "R.<z> = CC[]; f = z^5/2 - z/2 - 1; julia_plot(f)", one can obtain [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clicx.png)

Comment: One can also use SAGE and write   R.<z> = CC[]; f = z^5/2 - z/2 - 1;

J = []
g = z

for n in range(1, 5):
    g(z) = f(g(z))
    g = R(g)
    for (z, e) in g.roots():#all=True):
        J.append(z)

list_plot(J)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**: After reading the comment of lhf to the original question, I figured I might point out that what's going on here is simply inverse iteration.

---

How might we compute the roots of $f^n$, given its very high degree? Well, computing the roots of $f$ isn't hard, say we get
$$z_{1},z_{2},z_{3},z_{4},z_{5}.$$
Now, each of those points has five more preimages. The collection of all of those will be the roots of $f^2$. Each of those has five more preimages, giving 125 roots of $f^3$. The process we're describing here is exactly inverse iteration - a well known method for generating an approximation to the Julia set of $f$. Thus, that's exactly the set your process is converging to.

Since you mention Mathematica, I might mention that we can check this with just a few lines of Mathematica code:

```
invImage[z_] := w /. NSolve[w^5/2 - w/2 - 1 == z, w];
invImage[zs_List] := invImage /@ zs;
roots = Flatten[Nest[invImage, 0, 4]];
JuliaSetPlot[z^5/2 - z/2 - 1, z, ColorFunction -> None,
 Epilog -> {Red, Opacity[0.5], Point[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ roots]}]
```

[image]

Here's another way to think about why this might work. The roots of a polynomial $f$ are exactly the fixed points of the polynomial $g(z)=f(z)+z$, since
$$f(z_0)=0 \implies g(z_0) = f(z_0)+z_0=0+z_0=z_0.$$
Thus, the roots of your iterated function $F=f^n$ mostly lie on the Julia set for the function $F(z)+z$. There might be a few, isolated attractive points in the Fatou set.

Let's examine the implications for the fourth iterate - a polynomial of 620 terms whose coefficients have an absolute value of average size around $10^{23}$. The Julia set of a polynomial does *not* depend continuously on its coefficients, but it's actually close to continuous. We might hope that changing the coefficient of $z$ from $-4$ to $-3$ won't change the Julia set too much. We might even hope that, as we increase the number of iterations, the affect of adding 1 to the $z$ coefficient becomes less and less. The point being that we could examine the Julia set of $F$ itself, which is the same as the Julia set of the original $f$. Thus, we might hope that your roots are clustering on the Julia set of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just wanted to know : does the Julia set of $F_n = f^n + id$ is _exactly_ the same as the one of $f$, or only expected to be approximately the one of $f$? I tried to understand the relationship between $J(F_n)$ and $J(f)$ reading in particular the first and the third points of [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#Equivalent_descriptions_of_the_Julia_set), but I prefered asking you.

Comment: @Watson - No problem! To answer your question, the Julia set is invariant under application of the function, so the Julia sets of $f$ and $f^n$ are identical. The Julia set of $f^n+id$ should be close, but not identical.